# How to find same logos, UI elements using sikulix

Tags: sikuli, sikuli-script

I am new to sikuli.
I am using it for functional test automation of my java spring standalone application. I am having the same set of images(logos) at multiple locations on the screen. and they are generated dynamically as per the application data. In that case how can I find and click on certain buttons/elements in the UI.
Example: like, share, comment text/image will be there several times in facebook page. in that how to we click on particular buttons out of all.(facebook is just an example) i want the similar solution for my application.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve and what your problem is? Is there something you are trying and it doesn't work? Please provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're asking is- given a case where the same image or UI element is present multiple times on the same page, how can I specify one of these elements in one location versus the same element in another?

The quick and easy way to do this would be to capture a larger picture, like as much of the window as you can, and click the image in parentheses after the click action; this opens a window reading file, matching preview, and target offset.  Click target offset, use the mouse wheel to zoom in, and click on the exact point of the picture that you'd like to click.

It's possible to click in multiple places on a captured image, provided you use different click() commands, and you can set the target offset for each click() command without needing a new picture.

With just this one image, you can potentially click every square on the board provided you take the time to set the offset for each of the 64 click() commands it'd take to do so.    http://files.chesscomfiles.com/images_users/tiny_mce/cigoL/Chessboard.png

The more difficult solution would be setting up regions, and searching those regions for the matching pictures, but for what you're looking for this should- for more about regions and setting it up check links below.  Cheers!

http://sikulix-2014.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Based on your FB example you could use `setROI()` to focus on the top post on the page (imagine a rectangle that covers a complete post on the news feed) from there I would loop:

```
    if exists(profile pic):
        click(like button)
    elif exists(profile pic 2): # If you are testing more than one user
        click(like button)
    else : type(Key.DOWN) #repeat as needed
```

Getting the next post into the ROI may be tricky but using `WHEEL_DOWN` may help if you can adjust your lines traveled with each wheel click on your system.